# Selenium send text in file with unicode emoji

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium

i need to send selenium unicode
it sends everything in the file in the text box. it must send the emoji too and not just the text

file.txt

```
this is a line \uD83D\uDD25
```

```
with open('file.txt') as f:
    lines = f.readlines()

test = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//input[@title='Search']")
test.send_keys(u'''

{lines}

'''
)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

let's say you've a string like this :

```
str_ = "this is a line \uD83D\uDD25"
```

and you wanna parse that into `send_keys()` method, you can do it this way :-

```
test = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//input[@title='Search']")
test.send_keys({str_})
```